# (How) Is it possible to add text-links to a report?

Tags: civireport

This is to create a dashlet - hence links do make sense!

I know how to add a column to an existing template and create a new report template from scratch.

In each case my limitation is that I am reliant on database fields.

In the dashlet template that comes with CiviCRM I see this:

```
{sClass:'crm-contact-activity-links', bSortable:false},
```

But I don't know how to use this in a report.

I am editing a copy of the Activity Report template (safely copied to my custom php folder)

Answer (score 2):

In this case of altering an existing template - find the function that controls how the activities are displayed and setting the $viewLinks variable to True - as shown below.

```
public function alterDisplay(&$rows) {
    $entryFound = FALSE;
    $activityType = CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::activityType(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 'label', TRUE);
    $activityStatus = CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::activityStatus();
    $viewLinks = TRUE;
    $context = CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve('context', 'String', $this, FALSE, 'report');
    $actUrl = '';
```